# Sobre un árbol de resolución en Prolog

Tags: prolog

> Considere la siguiente base de conocimiento

```
c(v,A,A). 

c(l(X,A),B,l(X,C)) :- c(A,B,C). 

e(X,A) :- c(B,l(X,C),A).
```

> Como escribir los arboles de resolución correspondientes a la base de conocimiento y a las preguntas?

```
1. ?- e(X,l(p,l(q,v))).
2. ?- c(A,B,l(p,l(q,v))).
```

No entiendo nada, no se como resolverlo, que alguien me ayude por favor.

Vi un ejemplo al que sí le entendí, pero no puedo relacionarlo con este ejercicio para poder resolverlo. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes dar un poco más de contexto en relación a tu base de conocimiento y el dominio del problema? Recuerda que en Prolog, las mayúsculas se utilizan para las variables.

Comment: @MLStud mmh cómo qué tipo de contexto? La base de conocimiento son las 3 primeras líneas, i.e.  un hecho y 2 reglas. Así es, en Prolog las mayúsculas son para las variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vamos a exponer el árbol de resolución de forma parecida al del ejemplo que mencionas. Para ello denominaremos R1, R2 y H1 a las dos reglas y al hecho dados respectivamente como base del conocimiento:

```
c(v,A,A).  %% H1

c(l(X,A),B,l(X,C)) :- c(A,B,C). %% R1

e(X,A) :- c(B,l(X,C),A). %% R2
```

Así comenzamos el árbol de resolución con la primera pregunta u objetivo P1:

```
Nodo 1: e(X,l(p,l(q,v))).
      | la única regla que podemos aplicar es R2
      | (única que transforma el predicado 'e')
      | para ello se aplica el unificador más general siguiente (UMG):
      |  {X1/X, A1/l(p(l(q,v))} sustitución que transforma la pregunta
      |     a la forma de R2 de la siguiente manera:
Nodo 2: c(B1,l(X,C1),l(p(l(q,v))). 
                       /        \ dos ramas, ya que es posible aplicar H1 y R1
                      /          \
     H1              /            \     R1
con siguiente UMG:  /              \
{B1/v,A2/l(p,l(q,v)),X/p,C1/l(q,v)} \  
                 /                   \ UMG:{B1/l(p,A2),B2/l(X,C1),X2/p,C2/l(q,v)} 
Nodo 3: Éxito. Resultado:{X=p}        \
                                  Nodo 4: c(A2,l(X,C1),l(q,v)).
                                     /      \
                             H1     /        \ R1
                                   /          \
                                  /            \
                           Nodo 5: ...        Nodo 6: ...
```

Dejo los dos últimos nodos sin resolver y la pregunta 2 como ejercicio, ya que se calculan siguiendo el proceso descrito. Como pista diré que uno de los nodos termina en fallo ya que llega a expresión a la que ya no se le puede aplicar ninguna regla y/o hecho. De todas maneras la solución completa se puede observar para comprobar el resultado en el [siguiente enlace para la pregunta 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngmuilnbkyc1hyd/SLD-sample.png?dl=0), y en [éste otro para la pregunta 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tosmbvkudivp7w6/SDL-sampleB.png?dl=0).
 Dichos árboles de resolución fueron generados por la herramienta [JSldDraw](http://www.lcc.uma.es/~pacog/sldDraw/JSldJava/JSldJava.zip) desarrollada por A.J. Pareces García para la Universidad de Málaga. La herramienta requiere Java instalado, se ejecuta a través de un fichero por lotes '.bat' que también funciona desde Linux si lo ejecutamos en un terminal mediante:

```
     $ sh run.bat
```

Hay otras herramientas similares y más información proporcionadas por la mencionada Universidad [aquí](http://www.lcc.uma.es/~pacog/sldDraw/). El uso de estas herramientas es muy aconsejable, ya que el proceso de construcción de los árboles de resolución puede ser engorroso cuando se dan reglas y preguntas de cierto tamaño y complejidad.
Es habitual realizar la tarea de encontrar el unificador más general de forma lógica, mediante la aplicación de la sustitución que permita aplicar una regla, pero más adecuadamente se usa el [algoritmo de unificación de Robinson](http://www.lcc.uma.es/~pacog/apuntes/pd/Robinson.pdf), del que se puede ver su funcionamiento en la misma herramienta aconsejada JSldDraw, como se observa en los siguientes ejemplos: [A](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8mq501zyh6mxeuz/SDL-sampleB-res.png?dl=0) y [B](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k34wbola83b4291/SLD-sample2.png?dl=0).
Comentar que en ninguno de los problemas se produce ninguna poda en el árbol por repetición. Más información sobre el proceso y Prolog puede leerse [aquí](http://indalog.ual.es/WWW/prolog2005.pdf).

Espero que sirva de ayuda.
Paz.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda L.Jacob!

Comment: Encantado que te haya servido de ayuda. Saludos